# Does it follow from Least Action Principle that particles do not go back in time, or do we stipulate this?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, causality, action, arrow-of-time

Consider the action integral, $S[\gamma] := \int L(\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma}(t),t)dt$. We can always re-write it in terms of an arbitrary curve parameter $\tau$ which need not coincide with time $t$: $$S[\gamma] = \int L(\gamma(\tau),\dot{\gamma}(\tau)/\dot{t}(\tau),t(\tau))\dot{t}d\tau $$ (In both formulae the overdot refers to derivative wrt whatever its written argument is.) This new formula is more general, since it can accommodate arbitrary curves $\gamma$ through Galilean space-time --- even those which are not the graphs of functions $t \mapsto (t,\gamma(t))$ because, possibly, they double-back in time.

Carry through the usual analysis, where a stationary curve is to be found among *all smooth curves* of space-time joining $(t_1, x_1)$ to $(t_2,x_2)$. Do we find, as a theorem, that the winning curves are everywhere future oriented, or may it be the case that sometimes they are not? (I.e., is it an additional physical law "on top" that particles go forward in time?)

Comment: The answer is, surprisingly, both. In QFT we get correct answers with particles going backwards in time. But we also see that quantum theory continues to treat time as special compared to space, so that the path integral, if computed by time slicing, is only in the fowards direction. Life is supremely complicated.

Comment: Time is not a dynamic variable in physics. Time is that which the clocks show.

Comment: The integrand looks undefined for $\dot{t}=0$, but I figured we could extend the function to those points, assuming the limit toward them works out properly. I've just noticed that it cannot be so extended in the case of a free particle, but that's not unexpected. We already know these continue on geodesics; what reason do they have to go back in time?

But since the integrand can't always be extended to the $\dot{t}=0$ values, lets assume we have a case where it can be (crossing fingers that there are lots of interesting ones).

Comment: Thinking of it more, I think there should be no physically interesting cases. If we were just doing some pure variational calculus, maybe we could put in some $L$ for fun so that the stationary curves might double back. However, the $L$ which are common in physics always have $mv^2$ as a summand and so, like I just noticed earlier, will blow up at $\dot{t}=0$ in a way that cannot be fixed by any potential function $V(x)$ of position alone.

Comment: Why does it blow up exactly? In my calculations the infinities cancel out at the point where $\dot t = 0$.

Comment: @Trebor If $L = mv^2$ then my change of variables leads to the integrand $m(\dot{\gamma}/\dot{t})^2\dot{t} = m\dot{\gamma}^2/\dot{t}$

Comment: Yes, and take the free particle for example, isn't $\dot\gamma$ also zero at the point? Note that overdot means differentiation for $\tau$.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to guarantee that. For example, consider $t = -\tau^2$ and $x=\tau$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a parametrized timelike [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) $\lambda \mapsto \gamma(\lambda)$.

1. If $\lambda$ is an *affine* parameter [such as e.g. if $\lambda$ is proper time $\tau$], then $\dot{\gamma}$ cannot change between future and past directed.
2. However, if $\lambda$ is an *arbitrary* parameter [and we don't explicitly impose [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) or other regularity conditions], then $\dot{\gamma}$ could in principle change between future and past directed.

Comment: This is of course completely understood. The question was: are the latter curves included in the action's domain, or the integration region of Feynman's integral?

Comment: That depends on the theory/model.